# Python: __str__method causes "must be str, not NoneType" error only for one of two identical fields

Tags: python, django

I am working on Django app, but one of my model is causing `must be str, not NoneType` error when trying to edit its field in admin.

Stacktrace shows that the cause is my `__str__` method, defined as:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.restaurant.name + " ==> Looks for " + self.container_tag + \
           " with class: " + self.container_class or "[Not set]" + " , with id: " + self.container_id or "[Not set]"
```

Here are the fields as defined in my model class:

```
    container_tag = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    container_class = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, blank=True)
    container_id = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, blank=True)
```

As you can see, the last two are exactly the same. When I enter value into `container_class` (while ignoring `container_id`) and save, then everything works fine. But when I enter value into `container_id` and not `container_class` then I get the error above.

As far as I know the `or` operator should do the job and just "ignore" the field if it is empty.

For the sake of completeness, here is the line that triggers the error:

```
 " with class: " + self.container_class or "[Not set]" + " , with id: " + self.container_id or "[Not set]"
```

Comment: `"with class: " + None` will return a `TypeError` exception and `__str__` must return an `str`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Addition has higher precedence than `or`, so your expressions are effectively:

```
(" with class: " + self.container_class) or "[Not set]"
```

which isn't even close to what you want.  You need to write this as:

```
" with class: " + (self.container_class or "[Not set]")
```

Comment: Damn, thanks for quick answer. I suspected it would be something trivial, but never would have guessed higher precedence :-)

Answer (score 2):

For situations like these, I prefer string formatting to string concatenation.

```
def __str__(self):
    return "{restaurant} ==> Looks for {tag} with class: {cls}, with id:{container}".format(
        restaurant=self.restaurant.name,
        tag=self.container_tag,
        cls=self.container_class or "[Not set]",
        container=self.container or "[Not set]",
    )
```

Not only will this avoid the operator precedence issue causing your problem (as mentioned by @jasonharper), using string formatting with named parameters gives the added benefit of making the unformatted string really easy to understand.